# Print Multiplication Table

Tags: javascript

I want to print a multiplication table of user input number. But nothing's happening in the click But what's the mistake? or have I jump into this program early?

```
<body>
<p>Multiplication table</p>
<input placeholder="Enter the number" type="text" name="number" id="quest"/>
<br />
<button onclick="multFunction()">Process</button>
<br />

<p id="multiply"></p>

<script>
    function multFunction() {
        var a = document.getElementsById("quest").value;
        var i = 1;
        for (i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
            var c = parseInt(a) * parseInt(i);
            document.getElementById("multiply").innerHTML = a + "x" + i + "=" + c;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Typo: your `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: Have you checked the console (F12)? Maybe you'll see an error message there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of mistakes in your code:

```
var a = document.getElementsById("quest").value;
```

Should be:

```
var a = document.getElementById("quest").value;
//                         ^ No "s" there.
```

Next, you don't want to replace the `innerHTML` each time, you want to add a new row to it, instead. However, writing to `innerHTML` that often isn't a good idea. (each write to it causes your browser to re-parse the DOM)
Replace:

```
document.getElementById("multiply").innerHTML = a + "x" + i + "=" + c;
```

With:

```
result += a + " x " + i + " = " + c + '</br>';
```

And add `result = '';` at the front of your function. Then, after the loop, write `result` to the `innerHTML`

Here's a working demo:

```js
function multFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("quest").value;
    var i = 1;
    var result = '';
    for (i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++) {
        var c = parseInt(a) * parseInt(i);
        result += a + " x " + i + " = " + c + '</br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("multiply").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<p>Multiplication table</p>
<input placeholder="Enter the number" type="text" name="number" id="quest"/>
<br />
<button onclick="multFunction()">Enter the number</button>
<br />

<p id="multiply"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix `getElementsById` at the first line in `multFunction()` it should be

> getElementById

using browser console or plugins like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will make it easier for you to catch such errors